# Embedding php file in a webpage

Tags: php, html

I have downloaded a flickr photo php script for a client. In order to access the photo gallery you have to click on a link to go to the page. I am wanting to embed the photo gallery into the webpage itself so you don't have to click on a link. Can I do this by just copying and pasting the php code from the index.php in php tags within the webpage html or is it more complicated than that?

The gallery and all of the associated files are located in the codes folder as seen below.
Could I just include the file like `<?php include 'codes/index.php' ?>` in the portfolio.php's html?

[image]

Comment: As long as your file has a .php extension and your server runs php scripts, this *should* be fine. I say should, because it depends how well the script was written. Also you could use an iframe for this.

Comment: *running away to escape hate-mail for suggesting a frame*

Comment: Some servers don't allow to be `iframe'd`. If I do recall, Google is one of them. Test it and see with Flickr, but don't be surprised if it doesn't (un-tested for Flickr).

Comment: this gallery has a lot of other files it in. Would it be easier just to include the index.php file from the gallery in the html code?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change the webpage, in which you want to embed the gallery, to be a php file (change the extension, so that the server will parse it as a php file instead of a static html file).

Then you can put the gallery php code (including opening and closing php tags) between your already existing html code.